# ASP if x = y then include file a

Tags: if-statement, asp-classic, include

First, ASP is not my thing, coldfusion is.  I'm helping a not profit animal rescue group update a couple of seemingly simple items on their web site but I'm not proficient in ASP so it is proving to be harder than I expected.  The person who setup the site for them put the slider on every single page.  What they'd like to have done is to only have the page on the index.asp.

I came up with the following code logic but it isn't working.  I've researched it and know the *WHY* it isn't working but I cant figure out the *HOW* to make it work.
**UPDATED:**

```
<% if(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") = "index.asp") { %>
<!--#include file ="_slider.asp"-->
<% } %>
```

Any *constructive* guidance or links or fiddle would be much appreciated.  I don't plan on helping much with the site, just until the primary developer returns from active duty.

**UPDATED**:
I updated my code to include the slider as shown below but I'm still getting the non-descriptive page error.

```
<% 
Dim ThisPage
ThisPage = getFileName(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
if ThisPage = "index.asp" Then %>
    <!--#include file="/includes/_mainPage_slider.asp"-->   
<% End If %>
```

Comment: Are you sure your site is ASP Classic?  index.aspx  would be ASP.NET. These are different. Also, please describe what you mean by "it doesn't work", this will help identifying the issue.

Comment: index.aspx was a typo - sooooo sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Error Message I'm getting:  `An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator. 
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.`

Comment: @JeffBond I've updated the original question.  ASP Classic is what the site is supposed to be in.

Comment: Making progress - Classic ASP has to be enabled for IIS under Windows 7.  http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis Also, sending Script Errors to the Browser has to be enabled, too:  http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default.  We'll see if these "fixes" resolves some issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems.
First,
The Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") returns the full path & filename. If you only want to get the filename, you can use this function:

```
Function getFileName()
  Dim lsPath, arPath

  ' Obtain the virtual file path
  lsPath = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")

  ' Split the path along the /s. This creates an
  ' one-dimensional array
  arPath = Split(lsPath, "/")

  ' The last item in the array contains the file name
  GetFileName =arPath(UBound(arPath,1))
End Function
```

Second,
You're using **PHP**, but you said you were using **asp-classic**. Not sure if you knew that. The above example is in VBScript (the main Classic ASP language). If you are using PHP, then you should be able to figure out how to translate it.

If you're trying to ASP, then using the above function, your code should look like this:

```
<% if(getFileName(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")) = "index.aspx") Then %>
<!--#include file ="_slider.aspx"-->
<% End If %>
```

[Reference](http://www.kamath.com/codelibrary/cl005_filename.asp)

Comment: Code snippet I pasted was from an example I found on tizag.com.  Additionally, AFTER posting, I saw that the first line of code was `<%@LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>` instead of `<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>` which I have corrected.  In your code snippet, when/how does getFileName() function get called?

Comment: I have edited the second piece of code in my answer. It now includes calling the getFileName function.

Comment: I guess I'm missing something. If I keep this snippet of code `<% Dim ThisPage$$$
    ThisPage = getFileName(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))$$$
    if ThisPage = "index.asp" Then %>$$$
    <!--#include file="/includes/_mainPage_slider.asp"-->$$$
    <% End If %>` 
the page will error. If I take it out, the page will load (minus the include of course). $$$ = carriage return

Comment: After getting some configuration settings setup on my local PC, I was able to apply Tom's solution which worked, out of the box (well, once I corrected the file names (.asp) vs (.aspx).  I added the X on the name not realizing differences between classic ASP and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

What you have tried to do is right but the syntax is wrong for Classic ASP. Try...

```
<% if Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") = "index.asp" then %>
<!--#include file ="_slider.asp"-->
<% end if %>
```